# QT: Reading a xml file and parsing it using DOM parser

Tags: c++, xml, qt, dom

I am not that good with xml, but my basic xml file looks somthing like this.

```
<MAIN_HEADER>

  <HEADER>
    <TITLE>my_title</TITLE>
    <AUTOR>DNL</AUTOR>
    <NAME>John</NAME>
    <AGE>abc</AGE>
    <SEX>male</SEX>
    <PLACE>abc</PLACE>
    <INI_FILE>abc</INI_FILE>

  </HEADER>
```

what I want to do is, I need to find 2-3 tags, say for example NAME & SEX
and store the attribute(John,Male) in another variable.

until now, I have been able to make it read the xml file.

```
void MainWindow::XMLParser()
{
        QString path=MainWindow::getWorkingDirectory()+"\\0_Config\\";
        QString string;
        string = path + ui->ConfigFiles_combo->currentText(); \\THIS IS WHERE´IT DETERMINES WHICH XML FILE IT IS
        qDebug()<<string;
        QDomDocument document;
        //load the file
        QFile file(string);
        if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        {
            qDebug()<<"Failed to open the file";

        }

        else
        {
            if(!document.setContent(false))
            {
                qDebug()<<"Failed to load document";

            }
            file.close();
        }
        QDomElement root = document.firstChildElement();
        qDebug()<<"finished";

}
```

how do I make it search for the exact tag and store it inside another variable?

Comment: What version of Qt are you using? If you are using Qt 5 then the DOM classes should be replaced with the [XmlStreamRreader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamreader.html)

Comment: Then I would suggest look at the example code for the XmlStreamReader that is part of the docs, it should be good enough to get you started. Otherwise if you really need DOM and can't find examples or answers I might be able to provide some

Comment: Yeah i really need dom, it's pretty complicated with XmlStreamRreader. Can you please provide some example which are simliar to my case.

Comment: So are you preferring DOM or the stream reader?
My question is based on your question on the [Qt forum](http://forum.qt.io/topic/61089/reading-a-xml-file-and-parsing-it).

Comment: Yeah! DOM is very simple and easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why do you have `setContent(false)` again? Looks like you just copied **The Badger**'s code. Try this.

```
void MainWindow::XMLParser()
{
    // don't worry about path separator, Qt will take of it
    QString string = MainWindow::getWorkingDirectory() + "/0_Config/" + ui->ConfigFiles_combo->currentText();
    qDebug()<<string;
    QDomDocument document;
    //load the file
    QFile xmlFile(string);
    if (!xmlFile.exists() || !xmlFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)) {
        qDebug() << "Check your file";
        return;
    }
    QDomDocument domDocument;
    domDocument.setContent(&xmlFile);
    QDomElement topElement = domDocument.documentElement();
    QDomNode domNode = topElement.firstChild();
    while (!domNode.isNull()) {
        QDomElement domElement = domNode.toElement();
        if (!domElement.isNull()) {
            //qDebug() << domElement.tagName();
            if (domElement.tagName() == "HEADER") {
                QDomNode node = domElement.firstChild();
                while (!node.isNull()) {
                    QDomElement element = node.toElement();
                    if (!element.isNull()) {
                        const QString tagName(element.tagName());
                        if (tagName == "NAME") {
                            qDebug() << "Name is:" << element.text();
                        } else if (tagName == "SEX") {
                            qDebug() << "Sex is:" << element.text();
                        }
                    }
                    node = node.nextSibling();
                }
            }
        }
        domNode = domNode.nextSibling();
    }
}
```

This is my console output

```
Name is: "John"
Sex is: "male"
Name is: "Doe"
Sex is: "male"
```

Comment: Thanks! this totally works. but the problem is, the loop doesn't stop, not sure where to put the break .age  is: "5"
name is: "john"age  is: "5"
name is: "john"age  is: "5"
name is: "john"age  is: "5"
name is: "john"age  is: "5"

Comment: @ramtheconqueror, I reformatted your code, hope you do not mind.

Comment: @user5603723, you added the code that prints out the age, my guess is you did something wrong. Can you perhaps share what you have added

Comment: I cannot upvote you, because of my low rep. Thanks! this toally worked. You can now close the thread :)

Comment: @user5603723 Did you find the issue with the loop?

Comment: @user5603723 Threads cant really be closed, but since you accepted the answer that is good enough. I do suggest that you edit your original post and remove the last code snipped that you posted for me, for people that might look at the topic if they have the same problem. They will see that the marked post worked and work with that code as an example. The added code in the post can confuse people.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [QDomDocument](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdomdocument.html) docs, the example should be good enough: I am assuing the file is opened (your setContent() function call is not correct).

```
if (document.setContent(&file) == false) {
    file.close();
    return;
}
QDomElement docElem = doc.documentElement();

QDomElement headerElement = docElem.firstChildElement("HEADER");
if(headerElement.isNUll() == true) {
    return;
}
/* Get the name */
QDomElement nameElement = headerElement.firstChildElement("NAME");
QString name = nameElement.text();

/* Get the sex */
QDomElement sexElement = headerElement.firstChildElement("SEX");
QString sex = sexElement.text();
```

Edit: Look at the docs on [QDomElement](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdomelement.html) as well, there is some code that you can also use. My above code look similar to the last snippet in the description.

Comment: Thanks! i think i am pretty close to solving this, what i am actually doing is i am choosing a xml file from the list of xml files, but when i choose one the program stops. Any idea why? Please take a look at EDIT1 in my main code. I have put everything there. @The Badger